# How to determine coordinate bounds of the highlighted area

Tags: java, coordinates, bounds

I have the area like in the below. I am generating random coordinates between this coordinate map. When the randomly generated number comes (0.3,-0.3) I did easily program that it recognizes this coordinate belongs to Area F but how can I determine the bounds of A / B / D / E to recognize if the randomly generated coordinate belongs to these areas? **What are the bounds of Area E for writing an if statement to recognize if randomly generated coordinate inside of it?**

[image: highlighted]

Comment: I'm not sure if it would help you, but the java 2d api has functions for this. Look at the contains method in the Shape interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want to use an API, the purpose of this question is to learn the mathematical perspective of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### AREA `D` & `E`

- The line between the areas `D` and `E` is made of all the coordinates such that `x == y` and both `x` and `y` are negative, i.e `x,y < 0`. In other words the equation of the line is `f(x)=x`
- From the above information we can deduce that **all the coordinates such that `x < y` and both `x` and `y` are negative will belong to the area `D`**.
- Similarly, **all the coordinates such that `x > y` and both `x` and `y` are negative will belong to the area `E`**.

### AREA `A` & `B`

- Equation of this line is `f(x)=1-x` and both `x` and `y` are positive, i.e `x,y > 0`  (which you can easily deduce yourself if you take few coordinates that belongs to this line and try to figure out how you will get the `y` coordinate from the `x`)
- From the above information we can deduce that **all the coordinates such that `y < 1-x` and both `x` and `y` are positive belongs to area `A`.**
- And finally, **all the coordinates such that `y > 1-x` and both `x` and `y` are positive belongs to area `B`**.